# Unimportance of the metric for spin structures

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

I have some pedantic confusions when it comes to spin structures.  Let $B$ be a nice space (like a CW complex) and let $\xi$ be an oriented vector bundle on $\xi$.  If I choose a metric on $\xi$, then I have the corresponding frame bundle $F_{SO}(\xi)$.  Then I can talk about spin structures on $F_{SO}(\xi)$ being $Spin$-principal bundles $P$ together with an equivariant map $f: P \to F_{SO}(\xi)$.  Further, I can say when two spin structures $(P_1, f_1)$ and $(P_2,f_2)$ are equivalent, namely that there exists an equivariant map $P_1 \to P_2$ commuting with the maps $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Now, if I don't choose a metric, I can't talk about $F_{SO}(\xi)$ (although I still have $F_{GL^+}(\xi)$ for example).  So I have a few related questions:

(1) Can I define a spin structure without choosing a metric?

(2) Suppose I choose two different metrics, say $g_1$ and $g_2$ on $\xi$, and then I form the two different associated frame bundles (I'll be pedantic with notation for a moment) $F_{SO}(\xi, g_1)$ and $F_{SO}(\xi,g_2)$.  Suppose also that I have chosen spin structures $f_1: P_1 \to F_{SO}(\xi, g_1)$ and $f_2: P_2 \to F_{SO}(\xi, g_2)$, what does it mean for these two spin structures to be equivalent?

I'm confused because I usually see the set of equivalence classes of spin structures on $\xi$ referred to with no mention of the metric.  An equivalent definition of spin structures is that they are elements $\sigma \in H^1(F_{SO}(\xi, g); \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ that (for $n > 1$) restrict nontrivially to the fiber.  In a similar spirit to (2) (and in fact this would give an answer to (2)):

(3) For different choices of metrics $g_1$ and $g_2$ on $\xi$, is there a canonical bijection between $H^1(F_{SO}(\xi, g_1); \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^1(F_{SO}(\xi, g_2); \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ that preserves the spin structures?

Thanks for the help, I know these are pedantic and probably not so interesting questions... but I'm confused.

Comment: You can define a spin structure as a principal $\widetilde{GL_+}$-bundle $P$ and an equivariant double covering $P \to F_{GL_+}(\xi)$. Choosing a metric $g$, you can restrict this double covering to $F_{SO}(\xi, g) \subset F_{GL_+}(\xi)$ to obtain a spin structure according to the usual definition.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ahh, OK that makes sense, thanks.  I would guess then that conversely given the usual spin structure $P \to F_{SO}(\xi, g)$, this induces a unique $\widetilde{GL^+}$-principal bundle (up to equivalence) over $F_{GL^+}(\xi)$ that respects the inclusions and actions.  This would then yield an answer to (2) presumably, namely that the two spin structures are equivalent iff the induced bundles over $F_{GL^+}(\xi)$ are isomorphic as $\widetilde{GL^+}$-principal bundles.  But I'm not sure if that is true...

Comment: Also, I am guessing the inclusion $F_{SO}(\xi,g) \in F_{GL^+}(\xi)$ is always a homotopy equivalence, thus answering (3) by giving canonical isomorphisms of the cohomology groups.

Comment: That is true because, with respect to any metric, $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $\widetilde{GL_+}$ so the latter deformation retracts onto the former. The two bundles are related by the associated bundle construction.